# Dividir table em duas div

Tags: jquery, html, css, table

Olá tenho quatro div com tamanho fixo 300px cada, e uma table dento da primeira  div, preciso que quando essa table supere o tamanho de 300px o restante do conteúdo vá para a segunda div e assim por diante.

```css
#pg1{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 600px;
  width: 350px;
  float: left;
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
#pg2{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 600px;
  width: 350px;
  float: right;
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
#tbl{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="pg1">
  <table id="tbl">
    <thead>
      <th>01</th>
      <th>02</th>
      <th>03</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>AA</th>
        <th>BB</th>
        <th>CC</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="pg2">

</div>
<div id="pg3">

</div>
<div id="pg4">

</div>
```

Não estou de forma nenhuma conseguindo fazer isso e já garimpei a internet.

Comment: Paulo, eu fiz um teste aqui e pra mim funciona. Você chegou a perceber que as colunas da sua linha não atinge os `300px`? Tente colocar na primeira linha   `<th>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</th>`
        `<th>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</th>`
        `<th>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</th>`, isso vai atingir até a 3 DIV.

Comment: Ok o que preciso é que quando a altura da table atingir os  300px o restante da table vai para outra div

Answer (score 0):

Me surgiram algumas *alternativas* de solução para este problema, algumas são mais adequadas dependendo do contexto geral em que essa "divisão de tables" se encontra.

Uma *alternativa* seria verificar em algum evento, por exemplo, caso você vá incluir dados na `table` através de um click em um botão, então sempre que esse botão for acionado, após inserir o conteúdo na `table`, você faz a verificação se a altura da `table` ultrapassa o limite estabelecido em 300px, caso ultrapasse, você pode pegar o elemento adicionado, cloná-lo, removê-lo da table que excedeu a altura e adicionar na `div` mais próxima.

Segue um código de como fazer essa verificação na prática:

```
var table = $("#tbl");
  if(table.height() > 300){
     var ultimaLinha = $('#tbl tr:last');
     var clone = ultimaLinha.clone();
     ultimaLinha.remove();
     var tableProxima = table.parent().next("div");
     tableProxima.append(clone);
  }
```

Nota que no exemplo, eu [clono](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) uma `tr` mas isso pode facilmente ser aplicado para qualquer tipo de elemento.

A segunda *alternativa* seria mais apropriada par o caso de haver uma `table` preenchida, como o exemplo que você apresentou na pergunta, tendo em vista esse padrão de conteúdo `<tr><th>AA</th><th>BB</th><th>CC</th></tr>`, são necessárias 15 linhas para exceder o limite da altura (300px), logo, imagino algo como, dividir o número de linhas presentes na `table` (`$('#tbl tr').length;`) por 2 e verificar se o resultado é menor que 15, se for, deixa o número resultante como o número de linhas na table e o restante coloca na outra `div`, para fazer isso da pra usar a mesma lógica do código apresentado anteriormente, caso eu não tenha sido claro, fique à vontade  para questionar.